# agregar un texto abajo de una tabla en html

Tags: html

tengo una tabla de productos con sus respectivos precios, entonces requiero agregar abajo del precio de compra el total de estos. En el caso de que no se haya entendido agrego una imagen de ejemplo para que se logre entender.
link imagen de ejemplo: https://ibb.co/VQjVq7N
Me podrían guiar a como lograr eso por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que yo hice fue agregar un "< tfoot >" al final, dejar un "< td >" vacío agregándole el atributo "colspan" que lo que hace es indicar el número de columnas que ocupará la celda y dando el espacio para llegar a la columna donde quieres el Total
(También agregue un poco de estilo para diferenciar los td y centrar el contenido).

Espero te sirva. ¡Éxito!

```html
<head>
<style>
table{text-align:center;}
.celdas{background-color:#C7C7C7;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
        <tr class="celdas">
             <td>Producto</td>
  <td>Cantidad comprada</td>
  <td>cantidad vendida</td>
  <td>precio compra</td>
  <td>precio venta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Tornillo</td>
  <td>10,0</td>
  <td>0,0</td>
  <td>4.800,0</td>
  <td>0,0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Neumático</td>
  <td>10,0</td>
  <td>0,0</td>
  <td>800,0</td>
  <td>0,0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Neumático</td>
  <td>5,0</td>
  <td>0,0</td>
  <td>400,0</td>
  <td>0,0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>Desatornillador</td>
  <td>20,0</td>
  <td>0,0</td>
  <td>800,0</td>
  <td>0,0</td>
        </tr>
 <tfoot>
         <tr>
          <td>Total</td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td>5.800,0</td>
   <td>0,0</td>
         </tr>
 </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Segun tu pregunta y la imagen dada, solo debes de agregar dos etiquetas `<td>` vacias para que te de el espacio.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>producto</td><td>cantidad comprada</td><td>cantidad vendida</td><td>precio compra</td><td>precio venta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>tornillo</td><td>10,0</td><td>0,0</td><td>4.800,0</td><td>0,0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>neumatico</td><td>10,0</td><td>0,0</td><td>800,0</td><td>0,0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>neumatico</td><td>5,0</td><td>0,0</td><td>400,0</td><td>0,0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Desatornillador</td><td>20,0</td><td>0,0</td><td>800,0</td><td>0,0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td><td></td><td></td><td>5.800,0</td><td>0,0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Yo puse TOTAL para que quedara mas elegante, pero si gustas puedes dejarla vacia y agregar los textos en su respectivo espacio. Hazme saber que si quedo claro, si no, sigue preguntando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda